# Can I see a commit's real Author details in GitHub? (NOT just the GitHub username!)

Tags: github

When looking at a commit in GitHub, I want to see the value of the "Author" field in the commit.  As far as I can tell, GitHub will only show me the GitHub username.  Too see the author field, I need to fetch the commit and look at it locally, which is kind of annoying.

For instance, see this link:
https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/commit/b23261bdcda2d62fa8738f88bff8b6819df1f93a

You can see my GitHub username "gbirchmeier", but I want to see the values that I configured via `user.name` and `user.email` when I committed.

Comment: Github doesn't publish that information, so not possible for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not possible directly in the UI, it's only one click from there:
Just click <kbd>patch</kbd> and have a look at the `From:` line at the top.

[image: click patch]
[image: look for From:]

A blog post with more detailed instructions is available [here](https://www.thereach.io/blog/articles/how-to-find-github-user-email-addresses).

Answer (score 2):

Github uses email address to link username to a commit as [mentioned here](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)

> GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit to a GitHub user.

Hence not possible to see values configured via user.name

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible on the GitHub web UI.

One good possibility if you don't want to clone (that looks like a large one...), is to use https://www.githubarchive.org/ which exports to Google BigQuery with the query:

```
SELECT payload_commit_name, payload_commit_email
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE payload_commit_id = 'b23261bdcda2d62fa8738f88bff8b6819df1f93a'
LIMIT 1
```

If you are interested in mass email scraping, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456486/895245